# How and when are names removed from RMI registry if a server crashes?

Tags: java, rmi

If an RMI server crashes, when/how is the name of this server removed from the Java RMI registry where it registered itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If an RMI server crashes, when/how is the name of this server removed from the Java RMI registry where it registered itself?

Never. The Registry doesn't get told about that, and doesn't check it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple and robust example that demonstrates the issue:

```
public class RMITEst {
    static class Registry {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, InterruptedException {
            java.rmi.registry.Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }

    static class Server {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {
            java.rmi.registry.Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            TestService service = new TestServiceImpl();
            Remote stub = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(service, 0);

            registry.rebind("test", stub);

        }

    }

    static class Client {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws AccessException, RemoteException, NotBoundException {
            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(LocateRegistry.getRegistry().list()));
            TestService stub = (TestService) LocateRegistry.getRegistry().lookup("test");
            stub.test();
        }
    }

}

interface TestService extends Remote {
    public void test() throws RemoteException;
}

class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

    @Override
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("I am alive!");
    }

}
```

How to use it (all can be done from Eclipse):

1. Run Registry
2. Run client - you will get exception because object is not bound (but registry is working)
3. Run server
4. Run client - remote method invokaction will work, `test` is on lookup list
5. Kill server
6. Run client - `test` is still on the lookup list! - Connection refused exception will be throw.

So RMI Registry does not auto-unbind bindings even if their remote objects vanish e.g. due to a JVM crash.

Comment: Objects *are* being not only unexported but completely destroyed if the server JVM exits. Hence the connection refusal. What isn't happening is an unbind from the Registry, which is why the lookup still works. Not the same thing.

Comment: @EJP ye you are right, I was thinkig right, but used wrong terminology.